# How to delete filename in multiple directories linux

Tags: linux, find

Anyone know the command for linux (how to remove the file k.php and b0x.html in all directories and sub directories)?

I want one command like this (find .. -name "k.php") "is for find" and I Want one command to remove automatically that two file names from `../home/` directory and sub directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, that would do the job:

```
find ../home -type f \( -name k.php -o -name b0x.html \) -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: It Works, thank you!!!

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as accepted so that other users know your problem is solved.